# Perl dynamic hash of hash errors

Tags: perl, hash, hash-of-hashes

I am looping over a query and returning results.  I am trying to add a hash to another hashes. But running into trouble.

```
my %users_data;
while($sth->fetch)
{
    $mygroup =>
    {
        'fname' => $fname,
        'lname' => $lname,
        'address' =>
        {
           'street' => $street,
           'city' => $city,
        },
        'id' => $uid,
     },
}
```

how do I add the `$mygroup` hash to `%users_data` hash?

long hand would be.

```
my %users_data = (
 'salesmanager' =>
 {
    'fname' => 'mike',
    'lname' => 'john',
    'address' =>
    {
       'street' => '123 street',
       'city' => 'Brooklyn',
    },
    'id' => 12,
 },
 'garagemanager' =>
 {
    'fname' => 'Mark',
    'lname' => 'Jones',
    'address' =>
    {
       'street' => '355 street',
       'city' => 'Brooklyn',
    },
    'id' => 13,
 },
)
```

Comment: you need just to save the hash `$mygroup` in the other hash `%users_data` by using `$user_data{$mygroup}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply access the target key and assign its new value:

```
my %users_data;
while($sth->fetch)
{
    $users_data{$mygroup} = {
        'fname' => $fname,
        'lname' => $lname,
        'address' =>
        {
           'street' => $street,
           'city' => $city,
        },
        'id' => $uid,
     };
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I tried that but was getting errors.  But maybe I was doing something totally different.